Unsupervised short text clustering with covariates
I'm working on a project where I have to categorise short texts. I don't know the topics ahead of time, so the work is unsupervised.
Currently, I am using a Bi-Term Topic Model (BTM). I am seeing some decent results.
However, our corpus comes with a number of covariates that could explain topic prevalence. E.g. texts that are from country X are more likely to be from topic Y.
How can I take advantage of those covariates when estimating topic prevalence and therefore get a better classification? Normally I would use a Structural Topic Model, however I don't think my texts are long enough (perhaps 5-30 words).
Thanks for your help.
